# Postgresql date format error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm having problems when changing the date format for the datepicker.
I want to have the 'dd/mm/yyyy/ date format but postgres throws me this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid - PG::DatetimeFieldOverflow: ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "16/07/2014"
Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
```

because of its american way of saving the date format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set datestyle in your postgreSQL database as below:

```
SET datestyle = "ISO, DMY";
```

Comment: I edited the postgresql.conf file line "datestyle = 'iso, mdy' to 'iso, dmy' but I get the same result..

Comment: Have you restart postgreSQL after changing the file?

Answer (score 4):

The [`datestyle`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-client.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CLIENT-FORMAT) setting defines a default for your system. Consider @Ilesh's answer. The setting in postgresql.conf applies to *all* databases in the db cluster.

To make statements work without regard to the setting, use the [`to_date()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html) function to form date values from string constants:

```
SELECT to_date('16/07/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

Related:
[Store date with optional month / day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22456939/store-date-with-optional-month-day/22459892#22459892)