# How to search by date range

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm still learning in RoR and I have a problem to search table column (period) by date range (start_period, end_period). This is my code :

promotions_controller

```
  def search
    @promotions = Promotion.search(params)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

index.html.erb - promotions

```
<%= form_tag search_promotions_path, class: "form-horizontal bucket-form", remote: true do %>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <td>Periode</td>
        <div class="input-group input-large">
          <%= text_field_tag 'start_period','', class: "form-control dpd1" %>
          <span class="input-group-addon">To</span>
          <%= text_field_tag 'end_period','', class: "form-control dpd1" %>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

promotion.rb

```
def self.search(params)
  promotions = Promotion.all
  ????
end
```

I have tried to create a code for (start_period) & (end_period) in my model. But I have failed :( Can you give me a solution for my problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following method:

```
def self.search(start_period, end_period)
  Promotion.where("start_period >= ? AND end_period <= ?", start_period, end_period)
end
```

If you place these records on your seeds file (`rake db:seed`):

```
Promotion.create!([
  {name: 'p1', start_period: DateTime.new(2001), end_period: DateTime.new(2002)},
  {name: 'p2', start_period: DateTime.new(2001), end_period: DateTime.new(2003)},
  {name: 'p3', start_period: DateTime.new(2008), end_period: DateTime.new(2009)}
])
```

And execute

```
Promotion.search(DateTime.new(1999), DateTime.new(2004)) # returns p1 & p2
```

Comment: I have tried with your method but still not work. So I try this promotions = promotions.where(:period => params[:start_period]..params[:end_period].to_s) if params[:start_period].present? and get error -> PG::DatetimeFieldOverflow: ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "10/20/2015" HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting' Cant you help me sir?

Comment: Maybe you need to use "20/10/2015" or change the datestyle. It depends on your PG config. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24886533/postgresql-date-format-error