# How to compare components of a date as a single date in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using Postgres 9.3. given this table:

```
CREATE TABLE release_country
(
  release integer NOT NULL,
  country integer NOT NULL,
  date_year smallint,
  date_month smallint,
  date_day smallint,
)
```

I want a list of the earliest record for each release, in other words there can be multiple records in the table for the same release but different country. I want a list containing the release and the earliest date, but his will not work

```
select distinct  release, min(t1.date_year), min(t1.date_month), min(t1.date_day)
FROM release_country t1 
GROUP BY release;
```

Because it considers each portion of the date seperately. How do I consider the three portions as a single date, also having to contend with only the year portion being mandatory, the month and day portions may be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (release) *
FROM   release_country
ORDER  BY release, date_year, date_month, date_day;
```

I would consider storing a single [`date`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html) column instead of three `smallint` numbers. That's a lot cleaner and probably cheaper overall.

Explanation for `DISTINCT ON`:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Comment: Thankyou Ive never of the DISTINCT ON syntax before now. So I'm right in thinking it means having ordered the results take the first record for a particular releaseid and discard the others.

Comment: The main reason we are have the date field as three separate fields is because that is how they are entered by the user.

Comment: @PaulTaylor: Yes, you got the gist of DISTINCT ON. User input: I would convert it to `date` immediately (also avoid illegal values). Look into `SELECT to_date(concat_ws('-', $year, $month, $day), 'YYYY-MM-DD')`, adapt to your actual input ... More: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22456939/store-date-with-optional-month-day/22459892#22459892

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
SELECT distinct on (release) *
FROM release_country
ORDER BY release, date_year, date_month, date_day
```